# Build failed: CompileSwiftSources normal i386 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler

Tags: ios, build, ios-simulator, ios13, xcode11

I am getting the below error when I build my iOS project in Xcode 11.0 for Simulator 11.

> CompileSwiftSources normal i386 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler

[image]

How can I resolve it?

Comment: That's not enough information.